# Query to update a column data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do a query that update multiple rows in ddbb. I'm not sure if would be with UPDATE or ALTER table.

I have a database like so:

```
id | enrol | status | courseid | sortorder | name | password
622  self      0        152          1              somepass
623  auto      0        153          1                  NULL
624  self      0        154          1              somepass
625  self      0        155          1              somepass
626  self      0        156          1                  NULL
627  auto      0        157          1              somepass
628  self      0        158          1              somepass
629  self      0        160          1              somepass
630  self      0        161          1              somepass
631  self      0        162          1                  NULL
632  self      0        163          1                  NULL
```

I want update all rows that password IS NULL, I have this query

```
UPDATE mdl_enrol SET  password NULL WHERE  password IS NOT NULL and enrol = "self" ;
```

For some reason phpMyAdmin returns :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL WHERE password IS NOT NULL and enrol = "self"' at line 1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add assignment operator("=") when you set value for password:

```
UPDATE mdl_enrol 
SET  password = NULL 
WHERE  password IS NOT NULL and enrol = "self" ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot add "="

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)